# Using Buffer.from() with the contents of fs.readFileSync() makes a buffer with different data

Tags: node.js, buffer

```
let fb = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
let fileData = fb.toString("utf8");
b = Buffer.from(fileData, "utf8");
console.log(fb);
console.log(b);
console.log(b == fb);
console.log(b.toString("utf8") === fb.toString("utf8"));
```

I converted buffer to UTF8 string and again tried to get the buffer back using `Buffer.from()` but I can see that two buffer are different. However, if I again compare `toString()` result of these two buffers they are same.

Output of the above program

[image]

Comment: fs.readFile method read data as binary format. Since Buffer.from(__, @format) means make buffer to interpret as @format, what you trying to do is not exactly same action from fb.toString(). Try, Buffer.from(fileData).toString("utf8") instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `fileData` is not entirely legal UTF8, then per the `buffer.toString()` [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buftostringencoding-start-end):

> If encoding is 'utf8' and a byte sequence in the input is not valid UTF-8, then each invalid byte is replaced with the replacement character U+FFFD.

So, if you convert to a string and then back to a buffer and the encoding was not perfect utf8 to start with, then the process is not reversible because some illegal utf8 bytes will have been replaced.

Comparing two `.toString('utf8')` results will then each contain the same "fixed" version (with the replaced bytes).

The key here is don't convert a Buffer to a utf8 string unless it's really legal utf8 data.